# in python3, why is 'input' interpreted as a string?

Tags: python, function

If I put this code in the main program, it runs fine:

```
print("type of input=", type(input))
c = input('Enter q to quit, anything else to 
continue\n:') 
if (c.lower()=='q'): sys.exit()
```

and, as expected it says that 'input' is a built-in function.

But if I put it in a function I get a bizarre error:

```
def pause():
    print("type of input=", type(input))
    c = input('Enter q to quit, anything else to continue\n:') 
    if (c.lower()=='q'): sys.exit()
    return (c)
```

This prints that 'input' is type string, and then blows with

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The pause function is the first thing in the program after the imports.

Any idea what might be causing this problem?

If I put the pause function at the END of the file, and change 'main' into a function and call it after the definition of pause, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling `input()` tells you that `str is not a callable` it means you have overwritten `input` with a string somewhere earlier in your code.

Comment: Since `pause()` is a function, the redefinition could happen almost anywhere else in the code if it is at the top-level, since this would create a global variable named `input` that would mask the function. It doesn't matter that the function is the first thing defined in the file.

Answer (score 0):

@John's right, somewhere has to be `input` as variable or something, overwriting is not a good thing, so if wanted to keep as that before, (but after have no access to that anymore):

```
input = ...
...
del input
# back to regular input
inp=input(...)# works
```

**Or keep `input` variable, do:**

```
...
inp=__builtins__.input(...)
```

This is good because still have access to previous `input` variable, and do `__builtins__`'s `input` for real `input`

Comment: Any program which has to do `del input` or `__builtins__.input` deserves to be fixed to not use those.  This answer comes across as suggesting those things, when in fact they would be considered bad code in any code review.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I know, inefficient, it's just for stuff to work :-)